# How to run eventlistener on piece of html if it was created by js after the page load?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, aframe

I have a moving box in A-frame,

```
<a-entity id="myboxes">
   <a-box id="mybox" material="src: #material" width="0" height="4" depth="0.4" transparent="true" opacity="0.75" position="-5 -1.3 -15" rotation="0 0 0" scale="2 0.5 3">
      <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 0 5" fill="forwards" dur="5000"></a-animation>
    </a-box>   
</a-entity>
```

And I want to put it into a new position, If it reached the final position where animation ends, or if I clicked on it. 
I tried like this:

```
document.getElementById("mybox").addEventListener('componentchanged', function(){
     if((document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').x >-1) && (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').y >-1) && (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').z >4.8)){
        newBox();
     }
});

function newBox() {
        var X = 0;
        var Z = 0;

        var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 20);
        var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        X = val * plusOrMinus;
        val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 20);
        plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        Z = val * plusOrMinus;
        console.log("X: " + X + " Z: " + Z);
        document.getElementById('mybox').setAttribute('position', X + " -1.3 " + Z);
}
```

But this didn't work, so I tried like this:

```
document.getElementById("mybox").addEventListener('componentchanged', function(){
     if((document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').x >-1) && (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').y >-1) && (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').z >4.8)){
        document.getElementById("myboxes").innerHTML = "";
        newBox();
     }
});

function newBox() {
        var X = 0;
        var Z = 0;

        var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 20);
        var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        X = val * plusOrMinus;
        val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 20);
        plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
        Z = val * plusOrMinus;
        console.log("X: " + X + " Z: " + Z);
        document.getElementById("myboxes").innerHTML = '<a-box id="mybox" material="src: #material" width="0" height="4" depth="0.4" transparent="true" opacity="0.75" position="' + X + ' -1.3 ' + Z + '" rotation="0 0 0" scale="2 0.5 3"> <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 0 5" fill="forwards" dur="5000"></a-animation></a-box>';
}
```

But this way the box appears only two times, once when the page loads and the HTML runs, and once again when `EventListener` is executed. But why doesn't it run a third, fourth, etc time? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The problem is, that the eventListener has been bound on the "old" element. As soon as you create a new one, it will not work. Also, an id has to be unique. You are adding a new box with the same id. You could add the listener to a parent element.

Comment: @mat If I change to `document.getElementById("myboxes").addEventLis...` then it run only once.

Comment: When should the event be triggered? Is there any user interaction?

Comment: @mat when the animation ends, by `<a-animation attribute="position" to="0 0 5" fill="forwards" dur="5000"></a-animation>` or when is clicked, I didn't copy here, but I have a same `EventListener` for the click, which do the same thing, nothing more.

Comment: If you add an eventListener to the parent for the click event, you can check with event.target which element has been clicked. For the animation duration you could use timeouts, when there is no callback option for the animation framework you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the code with the handler to a function:

```
function rebindBox() {
    document.getElementById("mybox").addEventListener('componentchanged', function(){
        if((document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').x >-1) && 
           (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').y >-1) && 
           (document.getElementById("mybox").getAttribute('position').z >4.8)) {
            document.getElementById("myboxes").innerHTML = "";
            newBox();
        }
    });
}
```

And call it after recreating:

```
document.getElementById("myboxes").innerHTML = '<a-box id="mybox" material="src: #material" width="0" height="4" depth="0.4" transparent="true" opacity="0.75" position="' + X + ' -1.3 ' + Z + '" rotation="0 0 0" scale="2 0.5 3"> <a-animation attribute="position" to="0 0 5" fill="forwards" dur="5000"></a-animation></a-box>';
rebindBox();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working if you add the event listener to the box each time you create it:

```
document.getElementById("myboxes").innerHTML = (....)
document.getElementById("mybox").addEventListener('componentchanged', listenerfnc)
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ekLohgsj/6/).

---

But IMO you should approach it differently.

**1) If you need to change the position then change the position instead of overwriting the whole `innerHTML`:**

```
var newPosition = new THREE.Vector3( randomX, randomY, randomZ );
mybox.setAttribute("position", newPosition)
```

and restart the animation:

**a) set a begin event for the animation to start:**

```
<a-animation begin="start">
```

**b) emit it**

```
animationReference.emit("start")
```

**c) (optional) Check out Ngo Kevins animation component**
It should replace the `<a-animation>` soon, so I'd recommend getting used to it.

---

**2) Create the HTML element using `document.createElement("a-box)` instead of doing changes in the `innerHTML`**

```
var box = document.createElement("a-box")
box.setAttribute("position", newPos)
box.addEventListener("event", callback)
sceneReference.appendChild(box)
```